# Is $f$ integrable in $L(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, measure-theory, summation

Is $f$ integrable $L(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$

$\mu(E)=\sum_{n\in E\cap\mathbb{N}} |n^2+n-6|$

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}\cup\infty$

$f=(x-2)^{-4}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. $f$ is integrable on $X$ if and only if
$$
\int_X \lvert f\rvert\,d\mu=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lvert n^2+n-6\rvert\cdot \lvert n-2\rvert^{-4}<\infty.
$$
Indeed, $f$ is integrable, as the sum above converges.

Note. As Daniel Fischer observed, we should be careful when $n=2$. At $n=2$ the function $f$ blows-up, but the measure of $\{2\}$ is zero:
$$
\mu(\{2\})=\lvert 2^2+2-6\rvert=0,
$$
and hence the value of $f$ at $n=2$ DOES NOT contribute to the integral.

Comment: it is allowable to write like this, because of the measure hits for  naturals?